# Ubuntu 19.04 - Sounds is softer, even at 100%

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.04

I am running Ubuntu 19.04 on my HP Omen Obelisk and have noticed the the sound is much softer and lacking punch (even at full volume) when compared to Windows ( Im dual booting). Im running a simple stereo set up.

On the windows side Im running the Realtek HD audio that HP auto downloads. Device manager also lists Realtek R Audio

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have tried turning on amplification via Sound and pavucontrol, with very little luck. The sound becomes crackly after that point.

Any ideas what else I can do ?

[This is what AlsaMixer is set to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSlmE.png)

Comment: Does it have a sub-woofer or 4 speaker system?

Comment: It has a subwoofer. from the digital out port of the pc, I use a 3 way splitter to the sub woofer, which sends it front left and right speakers.

Comment: also WinEunuuchs2Unix it has a 3.5mm audio port, with which I use a 3 way splitter to send sound to the main, center and rear

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the statement: ***"Im running a simple stereo set up."***

Answer (score 0):

You need to install qasmixer and look at the master volume of your card . Set "show device selection" under view menu . As you will see Ubuntu 19.04 sets the alsa volume to a minimum level after start up. Restore that and go blast full .

Comment: I just installed Qasmixer and see that all the volume is set to 100%.